# 2.8 Beta Walk/Fly Mode No Wall Collisions?

Tags: collision

Is there any way to add collision to walls when in walking mode.  i'm trying to explore my scene without walking through walls and falling off into the void.  yeah i know there's fly mode also, but walking and jumping is more immersive.

i've checked in the preferences in the walk/fly section but there's no options for wall collisions.  i'm assuming one would have to apply some kind of script to activate the wall collision.  any ideas? thanx!

Comment: did you try to make them rigid bodies ? would that help ? I have no idea if walk/fly takes in account collisions at all, but this is what I would try in the first place since there is no any logic like it was in BGE.

Comment: yes i tried adding collision to them as well as making them rigid bodies but no luck.